# Server-side Analytics

Tags: playframework, google-analytics, analytics, playframework-1.x

I have a website the also exposes a RESTful API which my applications utilize.  I would like to perform some tracking on the type of requests we're receiving, but since the data I want to track is not behavior or interaction with a website, I'm at a loss.

I'm using Play Framework 1.2.4 (Java) server-side.  Is there an analytics service I can utilize to track the type of requests we're receiving?  I've used Google Analytics before, but since they mostly are in the business of client-side user tracking, that doesn't seem to be a good fit, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some Java tracking library in your controller, although I didn't use it, it seems that [jgoogleanalytics](https://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics/) is the tool you are looking for.